# Magento add an postDispatch to a post action after submit form

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have this controller :

```
class Mage_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();
        if( !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED) ) {
            $this->norouteAction();
        }
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('juron/ses');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function postAction()
    {
       $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
       if ( $post ) {
           ......
       }
    }
}
```

In the `/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.yml` :

```
    <events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
            <observers>
                <contacts>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>contacts/observer</class>
                    <method>postDispatch</method>
                <contacts>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
    </events>
```

And in the `/Mage/Contacts/Model/Observer.php` :

```
class Mage_Contacts_Model_Observer
{
    public function postDispatch()
    {
        echo 'Stop';
        die();
    }
}
```

Normally when I try to submit the contact form I should see `Stop` and the execution should be finished but not work like this. Seems the observer is not called. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance. Any ideas please ?

Comment: Just to be sure, you could add a `Mage::log('TEST');` to see if it is firing at all

Comment: Not added.........